# Maximum Likelihood Raster Won't Appear

Tags: arcgis-desktop

So I am currently creating a land cover map of all of PA. All of my counties will display except for one county. It doesn't even appear in ArcCatalog when the preview of the raster is selected. I reran maximum likelihood with the same signature file as before and got it to appear for a split second and then it went away and won't reappear. When I google this it says to adjust the display quality but that doesn't help. There is also no scale extent either. The only time it will appear is when I'm zoomed in past 1:8000 but again, I don't have a minimum or maximum scale extent set. Was wondering if anyone else has had this problem?

Comment: what file type is the raster? does it live in a geodatabase or is it a standalone file like a .tif? the fact that it appears at certain zoom levels suggests that you may need to delete or rebuild the pyramid files.

Comment: It is in a geodatabase. I have tried rebuilding pyramid files several times. The only difference I have noticed between this county and the others is that this is an "unsigned integer" and all the other counties are "signed integers" This could have absolutely nothing to do with that but it's the only difference right now.